# Deleting file from remote machine using ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

My page shows a grid with two column. 1st column has the hyperlink which when clicked opens the associated pdf (hosted on remote machine) in a new window. Internally I think the pdf is downloaded to the client computer's machine and he/she sees the cached copy. 2nd column has a delete button which when clicked deletes the associated pdf.

My problem is that if the pdf is currently open in the window, the delete button fails to delete the pdf because of sharing violation. I can go ahead and close the pdf and this allows the delete button to work fine.

I was wondering if I should be getting a sharing violation error since the client sees the cached copy of the pdf and not the original pdf?

Also, is there a way in IIS to release remote resources? Which might help in deleting the remote pdf even if its open on client machine?

Comment: It could be interesting to see this code

Comment: How are you providing a link to the PDF? A direct network share path or a web based HTTP path? Smells more like the former :/

Comment: Lloyd: Direct network share since it is to be used internally

Comment: Steve: Not sure which part of code do you want to see. Its a simple File.Delete enclosed around ASP.NET impersonation

Comment: @bluepiranha Your problem is (I think), if they're opening directly from the network it's no longer within the remit of ASP.NET. You'd need to use something like a HTTP handler and read the file on the server end and stream it to the user keeping it within ASP.NET.

Comment: Lloyd: Forgive my initial thoughts. How will reading files on the server allow deletion from remote machine. I have lot of pdfs and wouldnt like to bring them to the server.

Comment: @bluepiranha You're not reading on the server. You're reading the file across the network share. You'll know the remote filename so you can read/delete it. All you need to do is act as a *proxy* for the client.